# About pronunciation of "thank you"

Tags: pronunciation

About pronunciation of "thank you"

"thanks" [θæŋks] are usually [θæŋs].
"think so" [θiŋk-so] tends to be pronounced [θiŋ-so].

In a consonant group, the consonants, such as k, p, t. are omitted.

if you look at the most famous Merriam Webster dictionary in the United States,
"thanks" can be ˈ[thaŋ(k)s] omitted by 'k'.
It's explained.
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thanks)

In that sense,
"thank-you" [θæŋk-juː]
( As the principle that k pronunciation is omitted)

Is it possible to pronunciation that omits k as in [θæŋ-juː]?

I'm curious.

Comment: American.  That [θæŋ-juː] seems strange to me.  I can only think of Lawrence Welk on TV, in response to applause, saying this.  But I always attributed this to his accent.  (Wikipedia says he was born in a German-speaking community in the United States.)

Comment: /k/ after /ŋ/ is often omitted, especially before another consonant, like /s/. The velar quality of /k/ is audible in the velarization of the preceding nasal, and its voiceless quality merges with the following voiceless fricative /s/.  It is normal for stops in the middle of consonant clusters to be elided or reduced, especially at normal speech rates.

Comment: @HotLicks I hear "than**k** you very much". (or "thang **k**ew very much") Definitely not "thang you very much". What were you trying to demonstrate with that video?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> /k/ after /ŋ/ is often omitted, especially before another consonant, like /s/. The velar quality of /k/ is audible in the velarization of the preceding nasal, and its voiceless quality merges with the following voiceless fricative /s/.  It is normal for stops in the middle of consonant clusters to be elided or reduced, especially at normal speech rates.

Answer (score 0):

Using the dictionary you’re using https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thank-you no thank you is pronounced  (ˈthaŋk-ˌyü), so as you can see in thank you the k is not omitted.